# シェルスクリプトで複数行の文字列を区切り文字ごとに分割して配列に格納する方法

Tags: linux, shellscript, awk

例えば、以下に示すような文字列がある場合、これを `--` ごとに分割し、順番に配列に格納したいです。

一行のみならばawkを使えばいいだけですが、複数行で同じことをやろうとしたらIFSを変更するなど試行錯誤してみたもののうまく行きません。
方法をご存知の方がいましたらご教授よろしくおねがいします。

**対象の文字列:**

```
$ cat hoge.txt
あいうえお
ああああああ
かきくけこ
あかさたな
--
abcde
qwerty
asdfghj
--
poiuy
lkjh
mnbvc
--
aaaaaa
うううう
```

Comment: awk でも例えば `awk -vRS='\0' '{len=split($0, arr, "(^|\n)--(\n|$)")}END{print len;print arr[1]}' hoge.txt` などとすれば複数行でも対応可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「--」ごとに(正確に言うと「--(改行)」ごとに)レコードとして区切るのなら、RSをそのように設定すれば良いと思います。
「順番に配列に格納したい」の部分がやりたいことと合っているかわかりませんが、以下実行例です。

```
$ cat hoge.txt
あいうえお
ああああああ
かきくけこ
あかさたな
--
abcde
qwerty
asdfghj
--
poiuy
lkjh
mnbvc
--
aaaaaa
うううう
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="--\n"};{a[i++]=$0};END{for(i in a){printf "a["i"]=" a[i] }}' hoge.txt 
a[0]=あいうえお
ああああああ
かきくけこ
あかさたな
a[1]=abcde
qwerty
asdfghj
a[2]=poiuy
lkjh
mnbvc
a[3]=aaaaaa
うううう
```